# Why is $y$ not a coordinate here?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, mathematics, variational-calculus

Goldstein

[image]

> Consider first the problem in an essentially one dimensional form: We have a function $f(y, \dot{y}, x)$ defined on a path $y=y(x)$ between two values $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ where $\dot y$ is the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$. We wish to find a particular path $y(x)$ such that the line integral $J$ of the function $f$ between $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$,
> $$
> \begin{array}{l}
> \dot{y} \equiv \frac{d y}{d x} \\
> J=\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}} f(y, \dot{y}, x) d x
> \end{array}
> $$
> has a stationary value relative to paths differing infinitesimally from the correct function $y(x)$. The variable $x$ here plays the role of the parameter $t$, and we consider only such varied paths for which $y\left(x_{1}\right)=y_{1}, y\left(x_{2}\right)=y_{2}$. (Cf. Fig. above ) Note that Fig. above does not represent configuration space. In the one-dimensional configuration space, both the correct and varied paths are the segment of the straight line connecting $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$; the paths differ only in the functional relation between $y$ and $x$. The problem is one-dimensional, **$y$ is not a coordinate**, it is a function of $x$.

Why is $y$ not a coordinate? Clearly the author says that "the correct and varied paths are the segment of the straight line connecting $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$" therefore the particle moves along the $y$ axis although it's $y$ coordinate is also a function of a parameter $x$.

Comment: We want to find y as a function of x which extremizes J . Here x is the independent coordinate

Comment: Doesn't the particle move along y axis?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/664557/2451

Comment: Hi Kashmiri. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Hello Qmechanic. I had deleted that question. Also if I edited that question then the comments didn't make sense if someone read them since I was asking another question.

Comment: Ok, so the confusion is in notation. For 1D particle, here independent variable x plays the role of time, and we want to find trajectory y=y(t) or y(x). So indeed both x and y are coordinates for the particle

Comment: But Goldstein says y isn't a coordinate. In the post linked as duplicate by Mr Qmechanic, there one friend suggested that it was an error in the text.

Comment: It depends... In relativistic free particle lagrangian $L=\int \sqrt{1-\dot{x}^2}dt$, both (x,t) are coordinates (space-time) of the particle. For non-relativistic free particle, we can take t as just the parameter and x as our coordinate.